# Copying multiple ranges and concatenating them in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

My Excel sheet has multiple used ranges. I want to copy each range value and concatenate them. What I did is

```
Set tempRange = Union(SrcWkb.Worksheets("mysheet").Range("F1:H1"), SrcWkb.Worksheets("mysheet").Range("I1:J1"), SrcWkb.Worksheets("NWP").Range("K1:L1"))

For Each eachRange In tempRange
  tempString = tempString & eachRange & "/"
  MsgBox tempString
Next eachRange
```

I want to copy the value in merged cells F1:H1 and concatenate a "/" and value from I1:J1 (also merged) and K1 to L1. However, Excel throws "subscript out of range" error. How could I achieve this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by concatenate them? It looks like you are trying to create a new range that divides range 1 by range 2?

Comment: "Subscript out of range" means there is no worksheet "mysheet". tempString is not an object so you do not need Set. You cannot pick up a range in this way. Do you want cells I27, J27 and K27 concatenated? If so, pick them up separately. If they are merged, refer to them as I27.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite clear from your original post what output you need. Here is one option which may help you get started:

```
Sub ConcatRanges()
    Dim rangeOne As Range, rangeTwo As Range, rangeAll As Range, cl As Range, str As String

    Set rangeOne = Worksheets("mysheet").Range("I27:K27")
    Set rangeTwo = Worksheets("mysheet").Range("L27:N27")
    Set rangeAll = Union(rangeOne, rangeTwo)

    For Each cl In rangeAll
        str = str & cl & " / "
    Next cl

    Debug.Print str //Output: 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 6 /
End Sub
```

**Updated Post**

Dealing with merged ranges can be tricky. For example, the merged range `F1:H1` has value 36M. To access the value you have to refer to the first cell in the merged range. Example:

```
Sub MergedRangeDemo()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("F1:H1")

    For Each cl In rng
        Debug.Print cl.Value, cl.Address
    Next cl

    //Output: 36M    $F$1  <-- Only first cell contains the value
    //               $G$1
    //               $H$1
End Sub
```

Given this you can concatenate the values by using the rowindex `(1)` of the range:

```
Sub ConcatRangesUpdated()
    Dim rangeOne As Range, rangeTwo As Range, rangeThree As Range, str As String

    Set rangeOne = ActiveSheet.Range("F1:H1")
    Set rangeTwo = ActiveSheet.Range("I1:J1")
    Set rangeThree = ActiveSheet.Range("K1:L1")

    str = rangeOne(1) & " / " & rangeTwo(1) & " / " & rangeThree(1)

    Debug.Print str 'Output: 36M / 40M / 36M
End Sub
```

Comment: The solution works but for merged cell I get result 36 M///40 M//36 M// so it moves in loop in cell. and Hence no of "/" is equal to number of cell :(

Comment: Can you update your original post to show a sample of your data and the output you are hoping to achieve? It is not clear to me how your data is structured...

Comment: To be clear you want output to be: 36M / 40M / 36M. Is that correct?

Comment: got the solution :) One question do $F$1, $G$1 access each component of range cells?

Comment: Not really. In a merged range only $F$1 will get the value. I would avoid using merged ranges if possible as it can complicate things a little.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to concatenate I27 and L27 with a forward slash between and put the results on a different worksheet. This example does just that: concatenates I27 & L27, J27 & M27, K27 & N27 and puts the results in cells A27:C27 on the destination sheet. Note that the formula uses R1C1 notation with relative column positions; adjust as necessary.

```
Sub ConcatCells()
Dim sSource As String
sSource = "'" & SrcWkb.Worksheets("mysheet").Name & "'!"
DstWks1.Range("A27:C27").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & sSource & "RC[8] & " _
    & Chr$(34) & "/" & Chr$(34) & " & " & sSource & "RC[11]"
End Sub
```